# Prefix computation used for lexical analysis?

Tags: reference-request, parallel-computing, applied-theory, lexical-analysis

I'm preparing a presentation on prefix computation (aka scan, the generalization of prefix summation to any associative operator) for a class I'm taking on parallel algorithms.

Several lists of applications of prefix computation include lexical analysis (tokenizing), but do not cite a source for that.  I have failed to find any other reference to it being used that way.

Where has any description of the use of a prefix computation for the purpose or lexical analysis been published?  (Or, what was the origin of this misinformation?)

Comment: A classic APL one-liner for detecting unbalanced parens is to translate {'(',')'} to a vector of {1, -1} respectively and +\ (scan with addition).  Negative numbers, or the end not being zero, indicate unbalance.  I can imagine tokenization might be similar, although I don't know of a specific example.

Answer (score 1):

The important fact in this case is that the list `append` operation is associative.

Hadoop has "tokenize" as [one of its built-in parallel operators](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#tokenize).  The meaning of "tokenize" in this case is much less general than "lexical analysis".  They mean "splitting a string at a specific well-defined set of `delimeter' characters."  I doubt there is much you could do with a more general lexical analyzer (one where you are running an arbitrary finite-automata over a string.)

So suppose you need to split a string at all the space characters.  You are essentially creating a list of indices into the string.  The list `append` operation is associative.  So each processor generates the appropriate list of indices for the substring assigned to it, and then you append all the lists together.

Comment: That documentation doesn't mention prefix, so this doesn't technically answer the question.  I can see how to use a prefix sum to find a list of indices, which is helpful, but I still need a more citable reference than an answer on Stack Exchange.